# Swift - Array index out of range warning

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My code has an issue when I run the iOS simulator. It breaks and brings me to the line of code:`let targetUser = users[indexPath.row]` and says *'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (CODE=EXC_1386_INVOP,snbcode = 0x0)'* would anyone be able to help me figure out why?

```
class OverviewTableViewController: UITableViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var LogoutButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var ChoosePartnerButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var rooms = [PFObject]()
var users = [PFUser]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(LogoutButton, animated: false)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(ChoosePartnerButton, animated: false)
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        loadData()
    }


}

func loadData() {
    rooms = [PFObject]()
    users = [PFUser]()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "user1 = %@ OR user2 = %@", PFUser.currentUser()!, PFUser.currentUser()!)

    let roomQuery = PFQuery(className: "Room", predicate: pred)
    roomQuery.includeKey("user1")
    roomQuery.includeKey("user2")

    roomQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.rooms = results as! [PFObject]

            for room in self.rooms {
                let user1 = room.objectForKey("user1") as! PFUser
                let user2 = room["user2"] as! PFUser

                if user1.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {
                    self.users.append(user1)
                }

                if user2.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {
                    self.users.append(user2)
                }

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }
    }


}


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return rooms.count
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OverviewTableViewCell

    let targetUser = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = targetUser.username



return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you tried taking out the self.tableView.reloadData() at the top of your loadData function, as at that point your users array isn't populated

Comment: Perhaps numberOfRowsInSection should return `users.count` instead of `rooms.count` ?

Comment: @Gismay sorry I tried and it didn't work Thanks though, your guess was way better than mine. Martin, you're a hero! Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like @MartinR had nailed it. You're reading rooms.count in numberOfRowsInSection, but then looking up data from the users array in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

You could figure this out in the debugger by examining indexPath.row when you crash, and examining the size of rooms.count as well.

Comment: He was indeed spot on. Thank you for your reply Duncan. I will look at the debugger now and figure that out so I will know what I'm looking for next time. Appreciate the response!

Comment: You can either look at the variables view in the debug area, or type commands like `expr rooms.count` and `expr indexPath.row` (where "expr" is short for "expression", command to evaluate an expression and display its result.)